# How to download a file from Front End - Java HTML

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, spring

I want to download a file when I click a button on the front-end.

Front End

```
<td><a name="${flow.name}" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Report" class="generateReport"><span class="far fa-file-excel"></span></a></td>
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/flow/generate-report" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody void generateFlowReport(@RequestParam("flowName") String flowName) {
    TestFlow.generateReport(flowName);
}
```

Class

```
public static void generateReport(String flowName) {

//code to generate the file

  // Write the output to a file
    FileOutputStream fileOut;
    try {
        new File(FILE_DIR).mkdirs();
        fileOut = new FileOutputStream(FILE_PATH);
        workbook.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

How do I pass this to the front end now??

Comment: edit: it's an excel file if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

To give you an idea, this is how I did it in Spring MVC:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/yourRequestUrl",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE, "application/vnd.ms-excel"})
@ResponseBody
public Resource generate(HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    return runJob(response);
}
```

And in my `runJob` method I do the following:

```
private Resource runJob(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    final String fileLocation = "yourFileLocation";
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
            "attachment; filename=yourFileName");
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    return new FileSystemResource(fileLocation);
}
```